# how is the output of the following program is "2"?? Kindly someone tell me how did it come as 2

Tags: python

I have tried to understand it. How does output come as "2"

```py
def add_one(n):
    return n+1

def my_function(n):
    if n<5: return add_one(n)
    else: return add_one(n-5)

my_function(my_function(10))
```

Comment: What output did you *expect*? Try running it through e.g. http://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Yes, https://pythontutor.com is great as you can see visually what's going on step by step additionally you can also use the **python interpreter** in your terminal by typing **python3** and write the function there to see how your function behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is the correct output.

The inner `my_function(10)` argument of the outer `my_function()` is evaluated first. Since `n > 5`, `add_one(10-5)` gives 6.

Then you have my_function(6).
 Still `n > 5`, `add_one(6-5)` gives 2.

Remember `add_one()` function just adds 1 to the `n` parameter

Comment: thanks very much for sharing your insights. I'm new here and willing to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

First please use code tags. Second you just have to think.

10 is not smaller than 5 so it will become 6, because you subtract 5 and add 1.

6 is not smaller than 5 so it will become 2, because you subtract 5 and add 1.

You are calling the function twice, therefore the output is two.

Comment: thanks very much for sharing your insights. I'm new here and willing to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

you are running `my_function(my_function(10))`

first solve `my_function(10)`, 
 `my_function(10)` will be `add_one(5)` which is `6`
now `my_function(6)` is evaluated which is `add_one(1)`
which is `2`

Comment: thanks very much for sharing your insights. I'm new here and willing to learn :)